# Is it spelt "naïve" or "naive"?

Tags: orthography, diaeresis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [“Whereäs” as an  alternative spelling of “whereas”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/whereas-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas)

I've always wondered which is the correct spelling: "naïve" or "naive"? Are both correct, and it is just whichever you feel comfortable with?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/whereas-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas): the question of *naïve* is covered in the top answer.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: yes, good catch.  The question is different, but the answer covers this one very nicely; this’ll be a useful redirect to have to that one.

Comment: FWIW in my 68+ years this is the first time i've seen "whereas" with a diaeresis; for that reason, i'd not call [“Whereäs” as an alternative spelling of “whereas”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/where%C3%A4s-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas) a duplicate of this thread or vice versa, rather imho the two threads complement each other.  Typing diacriticals and the diaeresis is greatly facilitated when one uses the Windows [US-international keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/97738).

Comment: some **may** enjoy reading **[The Curse of the Diaeresis](http://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-curse-of-the-diaeresis)** by Mary Norris, The New Yorker, 2012-04-26

Comment: naïve is the correct and official spelling/writing but naive is accepted, mostly because people can't be bothered putting the two dots on the i.

Comment: As to the last comment: "people can't be bothered..." is a bit of an offense here, actually. :) More adequate would be to say "existing input methods make it too cumbersome for most people" (including e.g. myself, even as a seasoned SW engineer (i.e. someone typing a lot, pedantically), and even armed with a Hungarian keyboard, full of arcane diacritics already).

Comment: "correct and official" are just arbitrary rules, enforced by some idiots with power. people who use ï care too much about details and pseudo-problems, its their way to say "warning! im pedantic!"

Answer (score 25):

Either way. The *dieresis* is optional. Mostly it gets left off because people find it difficult to add it.

Actually, spelling it "naïve" is seen less and less, at least in the U.S., and is probably moribund if not actually archaic at this point here.

Comment: Presumably you mean the *spelling* with the diaeresis is moribund? In UK usage at least, the word per se seems common enough.

Comment: @Neil Coffey: Yes, I thought it was clear from context. I'll make it explicit just in case.

Comment: I guess it's hard to type it on computer.

And in written language people don't bother because second variant is accepted. 

Are there other words with this letter?