# “Zoe” or “Zoë”: which is the correct spelling?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, diacritics, diaeresis

I have a relation who has named their child *Zoe*, on the grounds that “in English we don’t use the dots”, but they pronounce it like the second version.

Of course I don’t want to argue that’s not the point, but in Continental Europe where I live, the dots mean that the letter should be pronounced. Think Dutch and German, and the second spelling is as far as I can see universally accepted, even in English otherwise the first spelling would rhyme with Joe.

What are the origins of the name, and should the dots be used in English too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diacriticals and non-English letters in anglicized loan words: keep 'em, dump 'em, italicize the words, or what?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13343/diacriticals-and-non-english-letters-in-anglicized-loan-words-keep-em-dump-em)

Comment: We used to use those dots. *The New Yorker* magazine still does. Is the trema borrowed, or is it reflective of the time in which the name became popular in English? [Info about the trema (two dots over a vowel to mark diaeresis)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/whereas-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas).

Comment: I think rather than proper names, a better question would have been about the word naïve, which is probably the most common English word with a trema.

Comment: @Sam: that question [already exists](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12747/).

Comment: @T9b Do you pronounce cooperation as coop-eration or co-operation?  How about coöperation?  Reexamination as reex-amination or re-examination?  How about reëxamination? Naïve differently than naive? It's not uncommon to omit the ¨, at least in some varieties of written English.  It's hard to see why it couldn't be omitted in Zoë, too.

Comment: I have it on good authority (from the spelling correction applied to a garbled diaeresis) that it's "Zock".

Comment: Unlike many in Europe,  English is not a phonetic language. That is to say, English spellings are arbitrary; they mean what most of us say they should mean, without rhyme or reason.
In some other languages, Zoe would be different with or without your dots or any other accent you care to mention.
In English you would first need to explain what difference either speaker or listener thought there could be…

Answer (score 17):

- The correct spelling is whatever the parents say it is.
- The correct spelling is whatever the child says it is.
- The correct spelling is whatever the generally accepted social surroundings says it is.

Sometimes these are different.

For the name under consideration, in the US, *Zoe* (without the diaeresis) is the majority choice (for all three). So you spell it different where you you’re from? Neat.

But surely the American version **is** from the European version, explicitly dropping the strange (to Americans) diaeresis.

Comment: Exactly - it would be Zöe if she decided to go into heavy metal for example

Comment: That's a [mëtäl ümläüt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut). :)

Answer (score 5):

The name *Zoe* comes from the Greek zōē, *life* (see etymology of *zoea* in [the Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/zoea). As an English name, it is rarely spelled with the dieresis. Some may be officially named *Zoë*, but they drop the dieresis, anyway. Another name that rhymes is *Chloe*, which is never spelled with the dieresis in modern English.

Comment: Wikipedia lists Zoe as "life" in Greek so your memory is well founded.

Comment: @z7sg: Thanks—heretofore ignorant about the distinction. Does your second statement refer to *Chloe* or *Zoe*? I meant *Chloe* is generally never spelled with the dieresis in modern [American] English.

Comment: Yes, Chloe.  There are a few here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloe Perhaps I am biased because I went to school with a Chloë (in the UK)

Comment: @z7sg: Yeah, I should have been more specific. One would certainly be hard-pressed to find a Chloë in the States. But, yes, Mitch's answer above is excellent.

Comment: "The name Zoe means life. (Read that somewhere years ago—don't have sources to back that up now.)"  What do you mean, you don't have sources?  Have you ever been to a *zoo*?  Why do you think they call it that?  Or you could check the Internets...

Answer (score 4):

The dots are there as a guide to pronunciation and are perfectly acceptable, even though diacritical marks are rarely used in English. *Chloë* is another name that is often spelled with diacritics.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_words_with_diacritics

There is an alternative spelling without the “dots”, for example:

> Zooey Deschanel

Answer (score 2):

I manually checked the top three links at [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=zoe&ls=a) and they all had entries for "Zoe" listed as a feminine name. I would guess that it is more common to drop the [*trema*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema_%28diacritic%29) in names than keep them. I cannot remember the last time I saw a person's name with a trema (unless they were from a different language.)

As somewhat of a contrasting source, Wikipedia's [entry on the name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoe_%28name%29) includes a list of variants:

> - Zoe
> - Zoí
> - Zoé
> - Zoa
> - Zoë
> - Zoey
> - Zoee
> - Zoya

Answer (score 2):

The words come from Greek originally, where the *e* would have been pronounced. The diaeresis makes this clear.

Answer (score 2):

I have a 6 month old daughter named Zoé.

We’re right in the middle of that discussion and I thought the internet would sort it out. Instead I found this question.

I was born in France, so to me it’s Zoé, but I spent most of my adult like in North America where the accent on the ‘é’ is kind of telling people the ‘e’ is not the regular ‘e’ sound in English.
My girlfriend is from Poland, the ‘é’ sound doesn’t really fit there so for them it is ‘Zoya’.
She was born in Germany and it looks like for people there Zoë is a better fit.

In French, with the accent on the ‘é’, the name would sound like ‘zo’.

So my belief is that the last letter is really dependent on the language of the place you live in. From one language to another the vowels can be hard to explain and have to be modified to fit the language you’ll be around in order for people to know how to pronounce the name.
Because of this, there is really no ‘right’ spelling. I tend to call her ‘Zo’ which makes everything simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema_(diacritic)#English

It signifies that the vowel is pronounced. It used to be more popular.