# Interested in 'naive' pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I'd like to know why 'naive'  is pronounced *ny-eve* but is spelt **naive**.  Where is the ***ny*** part coming from?  '*na-*' isn't pronounced  *ny*, and if the *ny* part is ***nai-***, then there is only *-ve* left.  This is about pronunciation

Comment: The pronunciation of a word isn't dictated by its spelling. In English, it's better to think of spelling as a *clue* about the word's pronunciation, rather than as a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: @Lordology Nah. *Cholmondeley* is odd. *Taliaferro* is odd. *Trottiscliffe* is odd. *Naive* is pretty regular.

Comment: @Lordology Choster was giving you examples where spelling and pronunciation differ far more widely than in 'naive'. Cholmondeley - *Chumley*, Taliaferro - *Toliver* and Trottiscliffe - *Trosley*. However, they are all either surnames or Placenames and so can perhaps be expected to be on the eccentric side.

Comment: @Lordology The difference being that choster's examples are of long standing and wide renown and arising from syllables falling away over the years through natural attrition or from assimilation from other languages, whereas 'Aohlysibeth' is a new coinage (unknown to google) which looks as though it is trying to make the name Elizabeth look Irish without adhering to Irish pronunciation, presumably for the sake of uniqueness.

Comment: Does anyone else pronounce it _nah-EVE_?

Comment: Say nah-eve slowly. Then start saying it faster and faster.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it spelt "naïve" or "naive"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12747/is-it-spelt-na%c3%afve-or-naive)

Comment: Not a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

French *naïf/naïve* does not have a falling diphthong, so its pronunciation wouldn't explain the use of /aɪ/ in English.

English doesn't have that many words where /ɑ/ comes directly before another vowel, especially not when the /ɑ/ is in a "weak" position (unstressed, or at least directly before another vowel with a higher level of stress). Words with /aɪ/ before a stressed vowel are a bit more common; e.g. *biography, diameter.*

The replacement of /ɑ/ with /aɪ/ is presumably an assimilation to the /i/ in the next syllable. In other contexts, other vowels may turn into diphthongs before a palatal glide /j/ in the following syllable: for example, *lawyer* has come to be pronounced with the /ɔɪ/ diphthong in the first syllable for many people, and words like *arroyo, Loyola, Toyota* likewise have /ɔɪ/ instead of /o/ as a syllable nucleus.

Something else that might be relevant is that apparently, people once used the pronunciation "/neɪˈiːv/", with an anglicized "long a" value for the first vowel. This might have made it easier for the diphthong /aɪ/ to eventually become established. Other words spelled with "a" that had variants with /eɪ/ and that are now often pronounced with /aɪ/ (rather than  ɑ) in its place are *Naomi* and *Israel.* *Dais* also can have either /eɪ/ or /aɪ/ in the first syllable (the French source word was a monosyllable, but the English pronunciation has deviated in syllable count).

Answer (score 3):

It's of French origin, if that helps. I don't speak French myself.

> Word Origin for naive
>
> C7: from French, feminine of naïf, from Old French naif native, spontaneous, from Latin nātīvus native , from nasci to be born
>
> Collins English Dictionary - Complete & Unabridged 2012 Digital Edition 
>   © William Collins Sons & Co. Ltd. 1979, 1986 © HarperCollins
>
> Publishers 1998, 2000, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2012
>
> Word Origin and History for naive
>
> adj.
>
> 1650s, "natural, simple, artless," from French naïve , fem. of naïf , from Old French naif "naive, natural, genuine; just born; foolish, innocent; unspoiled, unworked" (13c.),
>
> from Latin nativus "not artificial," also "native, rustic," literally "born, innate, natural" (see native (adj.)). Related: Naively .
>
> Online Etymology Dictionary, © 2010 Douglas Harper

So I'm surprised it doesn't end with -eoux :)

Comment: It is also noteworthy that the word is often - in English, not French - written with a dieresis over the *i* (_naïve_) to indicate that the two vowels are to be pronounced separately, not as a diphthong.

Comment: Is there a way to do that on a standard keyboard?

Comment: Not on an EN-US or EN-UK standard keyboard, but I believe EN-CA can do it, most European language keyboards can, and US-International can. I use US-International routinely because I need to do multilingual word processing.

Comment: @CrossRoads See at SU *How do I type accented character [in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/110605/)* and *[on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/110603)*.

Answer (score -2):

That's why the word is really naïve. So there are in effect two i's.

Comment: Could you back this up with any cited sources?

Comment: The diaeresis (two dots) over the ï doesn't indicate two i's; it indicates that the i should be pronounced as a separate vowel, and not as an "ai" diphthong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic).  So it's *na-ive*, and not *naive*.

Comment: As another example, the word "reentry" is properly spelled as "reëntry." That doesn't indicate that there's "three e's" in the word, it indicates that you pronounce it re-en-try rather than reen-try.

Comment: I think the typographical convention (of using a diaeresis to indicate a vowel pronounced separately) is and old one, and rarely used these days; ‘naïve’ is one of the few words you still see that use it (along with ‘Noël’).  It's much more common to use a hyphen (e.g. ‘co-operate’), or nothing at all (e.g. ‘cooperate’).