# Contemporary native English words with diacritics

Tags: diacritics, diaeresis

As I understand, *ö* in *coöperation* is considered archaic (or is it?) and words like *résumé*, *cliché* and *naïve* are copied directly from foreign languages.

Are there any contemporary native (non-borrowed) English words left that contain characters with diacritics?

*Update:* Note that a word from any contemporary dialect of English would work for this question.

Also, of course, as is noted in answers below, besides borrowed foreign language words, there are English words with diacritics, that were created from non-English given names — like *[ångström](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m)* for example.

Such words, arguably, also can be considered borrowed. And, at least with *ångström*, Wikipedia claims that version with diacritics is archaic as well.

*Update 2:* To clarify:

1. Contemporary = was a norm in XX century at least (preferably after twenties as well). When I said "archaic" in comments, I meant "non-contemporary".
2. Diacritics, which appeared in anglicization of a borrowed word (i.e. foreign original does not have diacritics), is acceptable. (So, *Brontë* surname would be good if survived into XX century.)

   (Anyway, is there a source where I can read about the rules which guide when diacritics should appear during "contemporary" anglicization?)
3. I'm not sure if proper nouns are in the spirit of the question — but if you know one that fits and is not synthetic (i.e. employs "metal umlauts" or imitates some foreign language), please share.

Comment: The trema in words like *coöperation* and *naïve* were diacritics that were used natively in English at one time, to mark diaeresis: two vowel sounds in a row (as opposed to a diphthong or single vowel sound marked by two letters). It fell out of fashion, but even in the early 20th century it could be found in various texts.  The New Yorker magazine still uses the trema in this way to this day. So, *naïve* arguably corresponds to the English orthography of the time.

Comment: Well, French *naïve* does have the same trema, so it is hard to say if it is a borrowed one or a diaeresis one (likely both).

Comment: @Alexander Gladysh: Yes, though it kind of becomes a philosophical issue at that point.  Is the "n" in *naïve* an English letter or simply borrowed from French (and so on)? :)

Comment: @Kosmonaut: That way or another — *ï* in *naïve* is dropped out of usage, as I understand. So — archaic. And it is a borrowed word. Does not fill the bill.

Comment: See this old discussion of [whereäs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/whereas-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas)

Comment: @Henry: This is a same as with *coöperation*, as I understand. Trema was there to mark diaeresis, but it is not used any more in modern English. Or am I wrong?

Comment: *whereäs* has been used, most recently in 1997 by some Japanese scientists.  So it is very rare.  I would not use it.

Comment: Given that a huge percentage of English words are of French or Latin origin, what constitutes an English word for this question?

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: well, hard to say :-) If spelling of a word has not changed during anglicization — this word probably does not fit the bill for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I regard *coöperation* as a *New Yorker* affectation, but it really a matter of style.  In the UK it will commonly be written *co-operation* to match the Co-operative Retail Societies.  The real difficulty is with the four-letter version: Harvard/MIT call their shop [the Coop](http://store.thecoop.com/).

As for the others, this is a matter of anglicisation of loanwords and changes slowly over time depending on how useful the diacritics are seen to be.  I suspect *naive* is now more common than *naïve*, and that the half-accented *resumé* is now used almost as often as *résumé*.

Comment: I am from Australia. We have never even heard of cooperation spelled that way!

Comment: Nobody in the US would've, either, if it weren't for the *New Yorker*.

Comment: Well, yes, but you did not answer my question. *Are there any **modern native English** words left that contain characters with diacritics?*

Comment: That depends on what you mean by modern, native and indeed English.  There are invented proper names such as *Mötley Crüe* or *Häagen-Dazs*, designed to look exotic.  There are *fiancé* and *fiancée* which, like *blond* and *blonde*, have an unpronounced gender distinction.  But I would not characterise any of these as *modern native English*.

Comment: @Henry: Modern = contemporary (sorry about confusion). English = American, British or Australian English. Metal umlauts and synthetic foreign word imitations in given names would not do. And I think that *fiancé* is a borrowed word, no?

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify some of the points.

Comment: @Jason - In addition to the New Yorker, Neal Stephenson uses these umlauts/diacritics/trema (perhaps we could have a similarly lengthy discussion on which term!) in his novels, notably the Baroque Cycle.  Is this used to sculpt the prose's feel towards the plots era (late 1600's, early 1700's) or is he taking a stand similar to the New Yorker?

Comment: @jon_darkstar I am pretty sure he only did it in the Baroque Cycle. Definitely a pretense.

Comment: @Henry Waaaaait…blond and blonde are gender-specific??? *Checks dictionary* I'll be damned. Until the '70s, they often were. Thank you for giving me my new thing for the day.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add that you can have diacritics on words that are not loanwords, but derived after the name of a person (e.g., a scientist). For example, the unit equal to 10<sup>–10</sup> meter is called the ***ångström*** (note the two cool diacritics), after A. J. Ångström.

Comment: But, well, this is a loanword too — after a fashion. *Ångström* is not an English surname. Also, FWIW, Wikipedia claims that the modern spelling lost the diacritics.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Alexander: how do you define an English surname? as DaG ask, what about Brontë?

Comment: Now you're asking hard questions. Well, A. J. Ångström was from Sweden — definitely not English. And, most importantly, the original question is about common words, not about given names (not sure how to say this correctly, but I think you'll understand what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Brontë](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bront%C3%AB_family#Origin_of_the_name) surname?

Comment: 1. Irish. 2. Archaic. 3. A surname. Does not fill the bill, I think. :-)

Comment: @Alexander: Of course, you asked the question, so you know what fills the bill, but: 1. *Anglicisation* of an Irish name (which didn't originally have a diaeresis). 2. XIX century is "modern" (or did you mean "contemporary"?). 3. It's a "word" (or did you mean "common noun"?). Half-joking, of course, but it still says something on how diacritics' use was felt in not-so-remote times.

Comment: 1. OK, a valid counter-argument. 2. Contemporary, right, sorry. 3. I'm a bit floating in the terminology, but I think that any English word except *proper noun* would do. Brontë is proper noun. :-)

Comment: I've updated the question, replacing modern with contepmporary.

Comment: Regarding proper nouns: well, after some thought, I think I will accept a contemporary (XX century at least) proper noun with diacritics, which either is "native" English or has acquired diacritics during anglicisation.

Comment: The father of the Brontë sisters changed his name from Brunty in imitation of Lord Nelson's Italian dukedom, and used the diacritic to show that the final 'e' was to be pronounced.     Nowadays few English speakers who have not studied a foreign language understand the use of diacritics, except possibly the acute accent on 'e'.