# Authoritative source on the diaeresis trema rule

Tags: rules, diacritics, diaeresis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Whereäs” as an alternative spelling of “whereas”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/whereas-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas)

I've got an impression that there is (or was) a rule in English:

If you have a rarely used word with two vowel letters in a row, corresponding to two vowel sounds in a row (as opposed to a diphthong or single vowel sound marked by two letters), you have to mark a second vowel with a trema.

For example: *coöperation*.

As rarely used word gets more popular and recognizable, trema is dropped from the spelling. In contemporary English *cooperation* is spelled without it.

Is there an authoritative source on this rule?

I guess, any linguistics work would do, Wikipedia would not. Something that I can cite and not be laughed at.

Comment: @Robusto: no, because I'm specifically asking about the authoritative source for this rule. The question thread you've linked to does not contain the answer to my question.

Comment: see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462/regulatory-bodies-and-authoritative-dictionaries-for-english regarding “authoritative” answers

Comment: and also, the question linked to by Robusto contains links to styleguides, which are the references for this issue

Comment: Because this question is a duplicate of the other question. To notice that a question is generally considered a duplicate if the answer to another question answers it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Cooperation* is not a borrowed word (which are more usually called *loanwords*).
- In loanwords, diaereses are just preserved as in the original language.
- In word formed as “prefix + word”, where the pronunciation might be unclear, some rare styleguides insist on adding a trema to make the pronunciation clear.

There is much more information about this [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/whereas-as-an-alternative-spelling-of-whereas).

Comment: Right, thank you. But I'm asking for authoritative source for the rule — either in form that I gave above, or in "prefix+word" form, or whatever else. Something that I can cite. :-)

Comment: I disagree with F'x as for _cooperation_ not being a loanword. Merriam-Webster defines a loanword "a word taken from another language and at least partly naturalized." Therefore, _cooperation_, which comes from Late Latin _cooperatio_-_onis_ and was brought into English in late 15th century, from Middle French _coopération_, is a loanword indeed, because it does not belong to the Anglo-Saxon bedrock of English.